# How to achieve a layout similar to "Aigner: Proofs from the book"

Tags: fonts, templates, typography, document-classes, book-design

The book [Aigner, Ziegler: Proofs from the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK) is generally hailed for it's beautiful Latex layout. An example chapter can be see [here](https://www.emis.de/classics/Erdos/textpdf/aigzieg/aigzieg.pdf). The book uses side notes, so it seems to be inspired by https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex.

But the choice of fonts and several details are different.  Is there a package/template available, which generates a layout equal or similar to Aigner/Ziegler? Or how could one achieve a similar layout?

Comment: Have you asked the authors? Perhaps the easiest way ...

Comment: *How to reproduce this output* is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0):

asmaier,

Latex grants you the possibility to do any type of composition by yourself, e.g., you can modify margins as you wish, therefore you can get some layout similar to the one you cite.

I have no remote idea if there is some layout similar to the one you cited, but anyway, if you want to have one similar, you can create it by playing with margins and columns and taking into account pair and odd page number or whatever pattern you arrange.

Comment: I would believe that a user who has a reputation score beyond 1000 is perfectly aware that you can actually change a LaTeX layout without pointing that out to them. Please only post useful answers!

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf You're right that asmaier is certainly aware of that. But he isn't the only person who comes across this question. Just because it's clear to him that one can modify the necessary things oneself, it doesn't have to be to anyone. So it's not clear to me that this answer can't at least be of some value. Also, his question "Or how could one achieve a similar layout?" really is rather vague (if not by some packages/templates, how else would you achieve a layout than by modifying things?). I think this answer is at least as specific as this last part of the question.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I am sorry for not being more specific, but I believe the question by itself was not much clarifying.@asmaier asked two things. 1) "Is there any package/template which can achieve such layout?" My answer was I have no remote idea, maybe you can help him with this question. 2) "Or how could one achieve a similar layout?" It is obvious that this could be achieved by playing with margins, page columns, header and foot sections, page numbers,etc. . I am a user of fancyhdr package myself, if I had to code that, I would use all above mentioned parameters and the fancyhdr. Better?